# React production build styling not loading on refresh

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a single page React website. Everything works fine in development mode. When I build it and run from the build folder, I encounter this one error:

If I visit any page, everything loads fine. However when I refresh the page, the styling doesn't get applied to certain aspects of the page.

Here is an example view file:

```
// Dependencies
import React from 'react';
...

// Style
import '../Styles/Landing.css';
...

// Images
import image from '../Images/landing/image.jpg';

// View

export default () => (
  <div className="landing-page">
    ...
  </div>
);
```

I'm new to React, and re-working an existing site, learning as I go. Is there a reason why the styling bugs out on refresh?

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: why you run from the build folder?

Comment: you should use npm start or npx start to use watcher and change the style if you using create-react-app